# swig numpy multiple matrix and array inputs

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

I'm trying interface a small C function I made into python using SWIG and the Numpy typemaps

This function is defined as follows

```
void nw(int* D, int Dx, int Dy, int* mat, int mx, int my, char *xstr, int xL,char *ystr, int yL);
```

And my interface file is as follows

```
%module nw

%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "nw.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
  import_array();
%}
/*type maps for input arrays and strings*/
%apply (int* INPLACE_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(int* D, int Dx, int Dy)}
%apply (int* IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(int* mat, int mx, int my)}
%apply (char* IN_ARRAY, int DIM1){(char *xstr, int xL),(char *ystr, int yL)}

%include "nw.h"
```

To test it, I used the following input

```
D = numpy.zeros((5,5),numpy.int)
mat = numpy.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],numpy.int)
x = numpy.array(list("ABCD"))
y = numpy.array(list("ABCD"))
import nw
nw.nw(D,mat,x,y)
```

But when I run it, I get the following

```
TypeError: nw() takes exactly 6 arguments (4 given)
```

I am really confused about how these arguments are defined.  Does anyone here have an idea why there are 6 arguments and what these arguments are?  Thanks!

Comment: Just guess. The `nw` takes 10 parameters and you 4 parameters using `%apply` directive. So you need to provide 6 parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow ... You're implying the %apply directive won't reduce my original parameters to 4 parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I think I have figured out the problem.

As it turns out, SWIG *really* didn't like the apply directives I made for the cstrings.

I should have be should the following directive instead.

```
%apply (char *STRING, int LENGTH) {(char *xstr, int xL),(char *ystr, int yL)}
```

Should have been following the cookbook more carefully haha